# Rotating the UIOrientation of a specific view

Tags: iphone, uiview

In a TabBarController the UI of a view will only rotate if all of the view within the tab bar can rotate as well (according to [app dev center](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW26)). Is there anyway that i can specify to rotate only 1 of 4 views within my TabBarController?

Answer (score 0):

If each view has its own ViewController you can define `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`
 for each one.

If they are just UIViews, you could set each one to have a specific `tag` property, then in the controller for the tab bar check which view is showing and allow rotation based on that.

Comment: i've already tried that but unless I return YES to the (BOOL)shouldAutorotate... method in each view none of them will rotate

Comment: All you view controllers instantiated by the TabBarController have to implement that message, otherwise the rotate won't work.

Comment: @Devraj yes i know that, that is my problem is there anyway to create an exception to this

Comment: If i didnt implement one of the views in the TabBar controller... how would i get to the view without having to use a navigation bar?

Comment: i mean could i since my TabBar doesn't rotate